# What merge type to use in this scenario

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I want to merge these two dataframes on the Administrative port, and include the Longitude and Latitude from df2 in df1 with the correct port.

What type of merge would i use?[df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4i5St.png)

[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4oWb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['Administrative Port'])
```